AWS API Gateway Service Integration passthrough response code
How to passthrough response codes from an integration request?
I've set up an API gateway method which makes an integration request to the ECS RunTask action. At the moment I have a default integration response defined for 200, which just returns 200 regardless of what the RunTask API returns. So the end user gets a 200 but they can see in the body of the reponse that the RunTask API actually failed.
From the docs it reads like I need to create a separate response for every possible response code? I just went the API gateway endpoint to return the same code as the integration request, is there a way to get it to just pass that through without me needing to explicitly define the return codes such as 403,400 etc?

This was the most helpful reference for me, so hopefully this helps you: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html?icmpid=apigateway_console_help.
Specifically, underneath integration responses, it says this:
For example, to map all 2xx HTTP response status codes from an HTTP proxy to this output mapping, type "2\d{2}" for HTTP status regex. 

You can implement something like the example below for (2xx,3xx,4xx, and 5xx). I didn't see an option to pass through the status code straight from the backend.


Seems a bit strange you can't just pass it through. This is somewhat helpful but still, i don't really want to swallow any 4xx into a 400

@Omiron Ever found a solution? I can't imagine why they would design something like this. Worst part that order is not guaranteed, so mapping for 503 and 5xx might still lead to the 503 to be handled by the 5xx mapping....

@peterulb sadly not, I gave up and wrote my api in node/express like I have done for years. Had been trying out api gateway after hearing good things but this really put me off just seemed so clunky

@Omiron Yeah,. I see so many constructs using 200 as a default mapping which is pretty dangerous. Too bad :/
